# Breaking a matrix into smaller sub-lists

Tags: algorithm

I can't wrap my head around how to achieve this. To be more specific, I would like to break the following matrix

```
matrix = [[7, 9, 1, 8, 9, 1],
         [4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 5],
         [3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
         [7, 9, 11, 6, 4, 8],
         [8, 9, 22, 3, 1, 9],
         [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

into:

```
[[7, 9,
  4, 2],
[1, 8,
 1, 2],
[9, 1,
 1, 5],
[3, 2,
 7, 9],
[3, 1,
 11, 6],
[2, 3,
 4, 8],
[8, 9,
 1, 1],
[22, 3,
 1, 1],
[1, 9,
 1, 1]]
```

> Or equivalently,

```
[[7, 9, 4, 2],
[1, 8, 1, 2],
[9, 1, 1, 5],
[3, 2, 7, 9],
[3, 1, 11, 6],
[2, 3, 4, 8],
[8, 9, 1, 1],
[22, 3, 1, 1],
[1, 9, 1, 1]]
```

Here is what I have tried doing:

```
def split([[]]) -> [[]]
  split_matrix = []
  temp_map = []
  row_limit, col_limit = 2, 2

  for row in range(len(elevation_map)):
      for col in range(len(elevation_map)):
            elevation = elevation_map[row][col]
          if row < row_limit and col < col_limit:
              temp_map.append(elevation)
  split_matrix.append(temp_map)
  return split_matrix
```

However, I had no luck in doing so.

Is there a way to do it without using libraries like numpy? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is going to be neater if we write a helper function to extract one 2x2 sub-matrix into a list. After that, it's a simple list comprehension, iterating over the coordinates of the top-left of each submatrix.

```py
def split_matrix(matrix, rows=2, cols=2):
    def helper(i, j):
        out = []
        for row in matrix[i:i+rows]:
            out.extend(row[j:j+cols])
        return out

    width, height = len(matrix[0]), len(matrix)
    return [
        helper(i, j)
        for i in range(0, height, rows)
        for j in range(0, width, cols)
    ]
```